# In which cases is the C compiler allowed to ignore the calling conventions?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, calling-convention, abi

For obvious reasons, a C compiler has to compile all functions that are externally visible to other shared libraries so that they conform to the platform's calling conventions and other ABI requirements. However, I've learned that it doesn't necessarily need to do that for functions that can be guaranteed to never be called from external modules.

How and when can a compiler determine whether that holds true for a given function?

- A static function is only visible to other functions in the same compilation unit, and therefore would be a good candidate for such ABI-breaking optimizations. But function pointers to the static function could still be passed to other modules. Does the compiler try to determine if function pointers are passed anywhere in the code?
- The gcc compiler has [some extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html) that allow symbols to be declared as default, hidden or even internal, and the documentation specifically mentions that this information can be used to perform some kinds of optimizations not possible for externally visible funcitons. What would happen if a function pointer was passed to external code for a function annotated as being internal?

What would be the best way to help the compiler to perform as much optimizations as possible, while still guaranteeing interoperability with other libraries? Should I just use the compiler option to define all functions as internal, and override that with an attribute for all functions that need to be externally visible?

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard *requires* that in all cases, two pointers to the same function compare equal.

The compiler can only perform ABI-breaking tricks if you declare the symbol as external *and* a pointer is never passed to external code.

> Does the compiler try to determine if function pointers are passed
>   anywhere in the code?

Yes, it does, if it wants to perform this optimization. The compiler can trivially know which functions have function pointer decay performed upon them, so it's not a big deal to know if you've taken the address of a function. Conservatively, the compiler can just assume all function pointers are passed to external code, or they might try for something more advanced.

> What would happen if a function pointer was passed to external code
>   for a function annotated as being internal?

Nothing of much interest- it must work.

Internal/external visibility is mostly about that- visibility. The compiler can only turn it into licence to break the ABI in relatively few cases.

> Should I just use the compiler option to define all functions as
>   internal, and override that with an attribute for all functions that
>   need to be externally visible?

Unless your library is composed of only a single translation unit, you would expect that virtually all functions need to be externally visible. There is no meaningful difference in C between "External but only within my library" and "External to all". However, in theory, you could try this. I doubt, however, you'd achieve much speedup and this would be a lot of effort for a non-trivial codebase.

Comment: On some ARM systems, there can be compatibility difficulties between code which expects floating-point values to be passed in the same way as other parameters, or in FP registers.  Were it not for function pointers, I would think the issue could be resolved by having a compiler that's producing code which uses the FPU produce a version of the function with a mangled name that uses FPU registers, and a "weakly-linked" wrapper with an un-mangled name that copies ordinary parameters to FPU registers and calls the mangled-named version.

Comment: A compiler proudicng code which uses the FPU and wants to call the FPU-register version would produce a call to the mangled-name version, and a weakly-linked wrapper which copies the FPU registers to ordinary parameters and calls the non-mangled version.  That should allow "universal" behavior between any combination of caller and called code FPU usage.  As for function pointers, I would think one could dodge the issues of ABI variance by saying that unless declared "specially" they always point to methods which use the most basic ABI.  Would that seem workable?

Answer (score 0):

> A static function is only visible to other functions in the same compilation unit, and therefore would be a good candidate for such ABI-breaking optimizations. But function pointers to the static function could still be passed to other modules. Does the compiler try to determine if function pointers are passed anywhere in the code?

Yes, compilers do "escape analysis" to see if given function is really only used internally or if it escapes through its pointer.

> The gcc compiler has some extensions that allow symbols to be declared as default, hidden or even internal, and the documentation specifically mentions that this information can be used to perform some kinds of optimizations not possible for externally visible funcitons. What would happen if a function pointer was passed to external code for a function annotated as being internal?

See my answer to your first point.